# Asking (for) permission

Tags: difference, word-difference, word-form

I have a piece of homework. I'm requested to say what speaker is doing. There are two questions.

> 1. May I sit down? ---> **asking permission**
> 2. What jobs should I apply for? ---> **asking for advice**.

Why we use **ask for** with **advice**, but not with **permission**? They are obviously nouns. Why don't they use **asking for permission**? Are there any difference between **asking for permission** and **asking permission**.

[link](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/common-verbs/ask-and-ask-for)

> Ask and ask for: typical error
>
> We use for when we request someone to give us something:
>
> I called them to ask for more details.
>
> Not: I called them to ask more details.

We also request somebody to give us permission. Why do they use **asking permission**?

Comment: You may fine this [article](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/common-verbs/ask-and-ask-for) helpful. See also [related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/234066/ask-help-permission-forgiveness-or-ask-for-help-permission-forgiveness) on ELU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say ***asking for permission*** and it means the same as ***asking permission***. You can also say ***asking for advice*** as well as ***asking advice***. Whether you use the preposition "for" or not, the phrases mean the same thing.

This is because "ask" is either *transitive* or *intransitive*. You can see the definition of "ask" here:

http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/ask_1

Here is a web page that describes *transitive verbs* in greater detail:

http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/transitiveverb.htm

Basically, a transitive verb requires an object for the sentence, whereas an intransitive verb links ***permission*** to ***ask*** through the use of a preposition such as ***for***. When a verb is defined as either transitive or intransitive, then it's up to the writer to decide whether to use a preposition or not. ***Asking for permission*** and ***asking permission*** have more or less the same meaning, but there may be instances when using the preposition could make the sentence clearer to the reader.

Comment: According to Cambrigde dictionary, there is a difference between ask and ask for: Ask and ask for: typical error  We use for when we request someone to give us something:  I called them to ask for more details.  Not: I called them to ask more details. They request someone to give them permission. Why didn't they use 'asking for permission'?

Comment: I believe my answer is correct. "Ask permission" and "ask for permission" are both acceptable and are both commonly used. They mean the same thing. You can also say "ask advice" or "ask for advice."

Comment: Check out this answer from the English Usage stack: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/234066/ask-help-permission-forgiveness-or-ask-for-help-permission-forgiveness

Comment: I believe that first comment below the question is correct. It is likely idiomatic to drop the "for" with certain words such as "permission," "forgiveness," "advice," etcetera. I know that must be an irritating answer. It's very common to drop the "for" in these situations.